# Extracting Text from url Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, url, text, nsdata

I am new to Objective C.

I was trying to extract text from a webpage and display it in a textView;

Except for when I run the app it appears to show html instead of the article.

```
     NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[self.url
                                   stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];

NSData *theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];

NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];

_viewPage.text = content;
```

The viewPage is the textview itself. How do I extract the text only?

Answer (score 0):

You have not included any code to extract the text from the web page. When you run "dataWithContentsOfURL" and it's a web page, then, as you have seen, you get the whole page.

To extract the data you need to process the results. In a simple case you can get the text with some string manipulation. In more complex cases you should look for a library which will parse the whole page for you. You can then access the parsed structure to get the content that you want.

Look here for an example of the simple case;

http://natashatherobot.com/html-css-parser-objective-c/

There are libraries for the more complex case.